# How can i make a div's right height different from the left

Tags: html, css

The image below shows exactly what I want to do[image: As you can see the right height is smaller than the left]

I simply want to remake this div. But nothing I have tried is getting me that shape

Comment: most websites use images there,not div

Comment: When you say images you mean I should use a picture that contains that text instead of a div? @Neptotech -vishnu

Comment: NO ONLY WHITE BACKGROUND IMAGE,the text is in HTML only

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS property clip-path.

Here is a sample code:

```
<div class='rating-container'>
</div>

.rating-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: path('M 0 200 L 0,75 A 5,5 0,0,1 150,75 L 200 200 z');
}
```

This is not the shape you want, but just to show you an example.

You can also use online clip generators like https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Yes, but clip-path can not give me that shape. I tried it last night and I could not get a good curve with it. Plus clip-path actually clips or cut out part of its div. So it will destroy the div completely because text has to go in.

Comment: The other way I can think of is again using clip-path, but also having 2nd div just to make the border-radius where clip-path fails. But this approach I can image is going to be hard to manage when we are talking about responsiveness. Can't you inspect the element you gave in the question if it's a website and see how they did it?

Comment: I wish I could but all I have is the image

Comment: The other way is by using path() - link to MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/path() 

This is definitely possible with path, but it would take you hour or two to figure it out if you are not familiar.

Comment: Thank you, I think that would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

## Use `path` with curves (`C` command)

- [Use this editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/)
- see the below image for some idea about editor
  [image]
- Idea from *@marian150 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71090260/14862885)*

  ```css
  .rating-container {
    width: 90px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: red;
    clip-path: path('M 0 10 C 0 0 12.5 0 75 10 C 75 10 87.5 10 87.5 20 V 30 C 87.5 40 75 40 75 40 C 12.5 50 0 50 0 40 V 10');
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class='rating-container'>
  some abcd
  </div>
  ```